# Find $(f^{-1})'(0)$ if $f(x)=\int_{e^2}^x \frac{dt}{\ln t}$

Tags: calculus

Let f(x) = $$\int_{e^2}^{x} 1/ln(t) \, dt$$
Find the value of (f^-1)'(0).
I am stucked upon this question. I know f'(x) is 1/(lnx) and (f^-1)'(x) is ln(x). by subing 0 as x, the answer will be undefined. Unsure how to move on after these steps. Please advice. Thank you

[My workings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDOp7.jpg)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

It is not generally true that $(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$. The correct result is that $(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$. This can be seen by differentiating both sides of $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and being careful to apply the chain rule on the LHS. Therefore, to determine $(f^{-1})'(0)$ in this problem, you should find $x$ having $f(x)=0$ and evaluate the reciprocal of the derivative of $f$ at this $x$.